# Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()

Tags: php, centos

O que fazer? estou tentando instalar

```
yum install gcc php-devel php-pear libssh2 libssh2-devel make
```

porém aparece a seguinte mensagem

> Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64

Utilizo CentOS release 6.8

Comment: Tenta yum --skip-broken install gcc php-devel php-pear libssh2 libssh2-devel make

Comment: Não aconselhável manter duas versões do php se a versão 5 pode te suprir em tudo quando bem usada e vice-versa, mas tente "pular" quebrados e erros na instalação se é isso mesmo que precisa em último critério.